# NAudio streaming voice chat c#

Tags: c#, streaming, chat, voice, naudio

I am very beginner with voice steaming 
I try to build a **Voice Chat application** I conclude :

- I should use UPD as ProtocolType in socket
- I should use NAudio streaming

The send mechanism (pseudo code):

```
    private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

        NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

        sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
        sourceStream.StartRecording();
    }

    private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sourceStream== null) return;

        send_UPD(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded);//sending data UPD
    }
```

I think the send will successful and the receiver will revive array of byte

The send mechanism (pseudo code):

```
        NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(/*my recived array of byte*/);
        waveOut.Init(waveIn);
        waveOut.Play();
```

**My question**
 Is the above true and what can i do with a array of byte in receiver (how can I play it ) ???

Answer (score 1):

The receiver should use a `BufferedWaveProvider`, which allows you to queue up audio data for playback as it arrives.